# get nt sid when user logs onto an asp page

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication

I'm wanting to grab a users NT SID when they access my page for secuity purposes..

this sort of thing

S-1-5-21-1614280859-2041256729-1847403543-2152

I can't seem to figure this out..

I saw a post that directed the OP to a book, but I don't want to buy a whole book just to do one thing.  In that post, they mentioned that the ObjectSID was part of the security token, but I have no idea how to get to this..

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks..

Solution thanks to Simon:

```
IntPtr logonToken = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Token;
WindowsIdentity windowsId = new WindowsIdentity(logonToken);
string strSID = windowsId.User.ToString();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you want the [WindowsIdentity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.windowsidentity.aspx) class.

You can get the current identity with `WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()`, and then read the [User](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.windowsidentity.user.aspx) property to get the [SecurityIdentifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.securityidentifier.aspx) for that user.